# Wordpress: output post title in lowercase?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I'm mucking around in my wordpress theme's `loop_single.php` to output the post title in lowercase.

My content has `non-ascii` chars so I thought the following would work:

```
<?php echo mb_strtolower(the_title()); ?>
```

But it does not work. It just outputs the title in the way it's written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just using CSS?

```
h1.post-title { /* or whatever the selector is */
    text-transform: lowercase;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-transform#Values

Comment: +1 This is better for search engines, people who have CSS disabled and Lynx users. :)

Answer (score 1):

did you try

```
<?php echo mb_strtolower(the_title(),'UTF-8'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else is ever trying to do this for non CSS related reasons in future this link is very helpful.

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/39145/how-do-i-convert-a-pages-title-to-lower-case

get_the_title($post->ID); is better than the_title(); in this instance.